# node js chai mocha "ReferenceError: Can't find the variable require"

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, chai

I am using grunt, mocha, and chai to run a basic unit test.  My unit test looks like the following

```
describe('SPSearchConnection', function () {
describe('#performSearch()', function () {
    it('should return zero or more results', function () {
        var spSearchConnect = require('../index');
        alert(spSearchConnect);
        chai.assert.equal(-1, [1, 2, 3].indexOf(5));
    });
});
});
```

Now when I run the test using grunt "grunt" I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

My gruntfile.js looks like this :

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Mocha
    mocha: {
        all: {
            src: ['tests/testrunner.html'],
        },
        options: {
            run: true
        }
    }
});

// Load grunt mocha task
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['mocha']);
```

};

My testrunner.html file looks like this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mocha Tests</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>

<script>
    mocha.setup('bdd')
    mocha.reporter('html');
</script>

<!-- Tests -->
<script src="tests.js"></script>

<!-- Tests -->
<script></script>

<script>
    // Only tests run in real browser, injected script run if options.run == true
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('PhantomJS') < 0) {
        mocha.run();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test has the line `require('../index')`, but the problem is that your test is going to run in a browser environment, which does not have a native `require` function (hence the `ReferenceError`). If you need to include a separate file you could us the ["requirejs"](http://requirejs.org/) library (which *is* intended for browsers). Or you could use a `<script>` tag in your HTML file? Or maybe just a simple Ajax call...

Comment: Using "requirejs" what should I include to make the require function available?  Can you give me a working sample.